# Event Log - EntryWrittenEventArgs returning Event ID's

Tags: c#

I am working on a simple C# Windows Service that listens to the EventLog via the "EntryWrittenEventHandler" handler and watch for logon logoff events and then write them to a DB.

The service was working as expected for a few days and then suddenly I am not seeing anything get written on logon and logoff events. I am seeing the EntryWrittenEventHandler handler be triggered on each new Security EventLog write...but within the EntryWrittenEventArgs class...I am seeing every entry be reported as "Event ID 0" and this message:

"

Message
"The description for Event ID '0' in Source '' cannot be found.  The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display the message, or you may not have permission to access them.  The following information is part of the event:"
string
message
"The description for Event ID '0' in Source '' cannot be found.  The local computer may not have the necessary registry information or message DLL files to display the message, or you may not have permission to access them.  The following information is part of the event:"
string
+ owner
{System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal}
System.Diagnostics.EventLogInternal
ReplacementStrings
{string[0]}  string[]
Source
""  string
+ TimeGenerated
{12/31/1969 7:00:00 PM}
System.DateTime
+ TimeWritten
{12/31/1969 7:00:00 PM}
System.DateTime
UserName
null string"

Not sure whats going on. Opening the EventLog on the server in question...I can see all the entries as expected. The date is also from 1969...which is weird as well.

Here is my code of what is going on so far:

```
    public Audit()
    {
        CanHandleSessionChangeEvent = true;

        //Start the EventLog Watcher
        startEventLogWatch();
    }

    private void startEventLogWatch()
    {
        EventLog eLog = new EventLog("Security");
        eLog.EntryWritten += new EntryWrittenEventHandler(EventLog_OnEntryWritten);
        eLog.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
    }

    private void EventLog_OnEntryWritten(object source, EntryWrittenEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            if (e.Entry.InstanceId.ToString() == "4624")
            {
                EventAudit eventAuditEntry = new EventAudit();
                eventAuditEntry = LogonEvent(e);

                if (eventAuditEntry.ADUserName != null)
                {
                    WriteDBEntry(eventAuditEntry);
                }
            }
            else if (e.Entry.InstanceId.ToString() == "4647")
            {
                EventAudit eventAuditEntry = new EventAudit();
                eventAuditEntry = LogoffEvent(e);

                if (eventAuditEntry.ADUserName != null)
                {
                    WriteDBEntry(eventAuditEntry);
                }
            }          
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            eventLog1.WriteEntry("A general error has occured. The error message is as follows: " + ex.Message.ToString(), EventLogEntryType.Error, 2001);
        }
    }
```

Comment: One thing I noticed today when debugging this service on a working server and a server where its not working.

On a working server where the service works as expected...I can see it loads two MessageLibraries: wevtapi.dll and adtschema.dll

On a server where the service isnt working and producing the results above...it only loads the wevtapi.dll MessageLibrary. Doing some quick searches...it does sound like the adtschema.dll missing could be the culprit. Not exactly sure what caused the service to stop loading the adtschema.dll library though.